# I keep getting this error when i run my functions:- SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

I don't know why I am getting a error message when i run addItem() saying:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I have all my reading and writing to files closed, and I'm using `raw_input` functions. I think something is wrong with my readfrom() function, but I don't know what exactly.

```
import ast


def writeTo():

    itemx=",".join(map(str,itemx))
    with open("ListItemz.txt","a") as filewrite:
        filewrite.write(str(itemx)+"\n")
    filewrite.close()

def readfrom():

    fileread=open("ListItemz.txt","r")
    fr=fileread.readlines()
    fr=fr[len(fr)-1]
    itemx=list(ast.literal_eval(fr))
    fileread.close()

itemx=[]

def addItem():

    global itemx
    if  itemx==[]:
        itemx=[]
    else:
        """
        about to read file:
        """
    readfrom()
    dowhile="y"
    while dowhile =="y":
        item=raw_input("please enter item discription, or barcode No. ")
        if itemx!=[]:
            for y in itemx: 
                if item==y[0] or item==y[1]:
                    raise TypeError("This Item is already added")
        case=int(raw_input("Enter how much holds in one (1) case: "))
        caseNo=int(raw_input("how many cases are there?  "))
        for i in stockList():
            if item==i[1] or item==i[0]:
                itemx+=[[i[0],i[1],case,caseNo]]
                print "ITEM ADDED"
        dowhile=raw_input("Do you want to add another?(Y/N) ")
        """
        about to write itemx to a file:
        """
        writeTo()
    return itemx
```

Comment: What's the value of `fr=fr[len(fr)-1]`? Something like `ast.literal_eval("(1, ")` can produce the same error, post the full error traceback.

Comment: I get no such error for the code posted here. The EOF error means Python was expecting something *else* at the of the file, but you didn't provide it. Is this the *whole* file?

Comment: You don't need to `close()` files that have already been closed by the `with` construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the error comes from the code above. The parsing and syntax refer to the Python parser trying to read your program, not from the reading or writing you do. As the program above is not complete - there is no main program - it's difficult to see where the error could originate. Or maybe there *is* a main program, but the indentation is off.

There's also this strange construct:

```
if  itemx==[]:
    itemx=[]
```

Is that really correct?

To try and pinpoint the problem, you can use the (under-appreciated) Python debugger (pdb). Add an `import pdb` at the top, and insert a line where you want to stop the program:

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

You can then do:

```
n<enter> to advance a line of code
p variable<enter> to see the value of a variable
c<enter> to continue at full speed
... and a lot more - see the pdb manual.
```

Just advance through the program till the error pops.

Answer (score 2):

the file i wrote to (ListItemz.txt) had complications so i just deleted very thing and started a fresh.